# listing resolved conflicts

Tags: git

When we detect a conflict and we want to resolve the conflict by accepting our version using.

```
git checkout HEAD -- file-name 
or 
git checkout --ours -- file-name
```

if I commit using no commit message git automatically shows the file in the commit message, i.e. it shows me the file that I resolved.

However git status/diff does not show it up or I don't seem to be able to get a list of the files in this category?

The .git/MERGE_MSG appears to capture the conflicted files from the merge.

Comment: You should be able to see them in `git status` if you haven't `git add`ed them yet. They show up as unresolved conflicts even though you have started to resolve them by checking out a file over them. Is that what you mean?

Comment: git status does not show them because I have done a git checkout HEAD -- file-name